# How to capture the user id that a user logged in with in Grails

Tags: grails

How do I capture the user id that a user logged in with to supply that user id to my form instead of requiring that user to enter such information on a form?

Comment: We need many more details to be able to help. What are you trying to do? What are you using for security/authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Security Core you have to inject the SpringSecurityService in the Service or Controller

```
class MyClass{

SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

...

def action(){
    Long userId = springSecurityService.currentUser?.id
}}
```

Comment: I did try the above and I got an error (unable to resolve class SpringSecurityService) SpringSecurityService. how do I inject it in the Controller? Please let me know where exactly to put the code and thanks for your help.

Comment: @Stan are you using Spring Security Core plugin?? If you do, here you can find all helper classes doc.  https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService